# Is there Reference Count in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I've just installed **Resharper Ultimate 9.2** and would like to know whether it is possible to turn **Reference Count**? Like **Visual Studio 2015 Professional** has:

[image: editor options]

I have **Visual Studio 2015 Community**.

Comment: ReSharper does not plug into codelens. You can hit Ctrl+F12 to find all references for a specific identifier but nothing built into codelens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, CodeLens is not present at all in the Community Edition.

As per the [Visual Studio 2015 feature matrix](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/):

[image: Visual Studio 2015 feature matrix and CodeLens]

As such, even if ReSharper could plug into CodeLens it wouldn't work with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

In any case, ReSharper **does not** plug into CodeLens so even in the Pro version ReSharper would make no different.

To ask ReSharper to manually find all references to a given identifier put the cursor inside it and hit Ctrl+F12. This will, however, show a list of references for that single identifier, and is not live for all identifiers/members in your current file. It is also a snapshot of the references present when you hit Ctrl+F12 and if you after this add or remove or change any such references, the list does not update.

In short, ReSharper doesn't have the functionality you ask for and CodeLens is not present in Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not in ReSharper but CodeLens is now available in **Visual Studio 2019, including Community edition**

See [What's New in Visual Studio 2019](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt848632.aspx)

> CodeLens for Everyone
>
> CodeLens has been a feature found only in Visual
>   Studio Enterprise, but that will change in an upcoming preview of
>   Visual Studio 2019, when it will also be available for the Community
>   edition, likely in 2019. CodeLens shows the number of references a
>   type or method has, information about unit tests covering the method,
>   and data directly from Application Insights.